# Getting a: "TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable" error in program related to Bessel functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

The aim of the program is to:

"Write a python function *J(m,x)* that calculates the value of *Jm(x)* using the trapezium rule, with N = 10000. Use your function in a program to make a plot of the Bessel functions *J0(x), J1(x) and J2(x)* as a function of *x* from *x = 0* to *x = 20*."

*Jm(x) = (1/pi) . integrate[cos(m.theta - x.sin(theta))] from 0 --> pi*

and is part of an intro to python module for a 1st year physics degree.

The line the type error originates from is from my function to integrate a function using the trapezium rule:

```
def integrate(f, a, b, N:int):
h = (b-a) / N
s = 0

for i in range(1,N):
    c = f(a + i*h)
    s = s + c

Area = h*(0.5*f(a) + 0.5*f(b) + s)
return Area
```

The error refers to the line " c = f(a + i*h) ": "TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable".

Given this function works in other programs I've made, I'm not sure what the origin of this error is. I am aware that scipy.integrate.quad could do the integration better, however we've been asked not to use it to demonstrate learning different techniques.

One possibility is that the problem is caused by other parts of the larger program. As someone very new to programming in general it seems likely that other problems exist which I haven't run into yet as the program doesn't reach them before turning up an error. The rest of the code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np

#Defining how to integrate a function using the trapezium rule
def integrate(f, a, b, N:int):
    h = (b-a) / N       
    s = 0               

    for i in range(1,N):        
        c = f(a + i*h)
        s = s + c

    Area = h*(0.5*f(a) + 0.5*f(b) + s)
    return Area

def func(o, m, x):
    return np.cos(m*o - x*np.sin(o))        #1st attempt at defining the bessel function

def J(m,x):     
    return (1 / np.pi) * integrate(func(0, m, x), 0, np.pi, 10000)

#Produce range of x-values from 0 to 20.
xvals = np.linspace(0,20,200)

#Calculating the value of the bessel function for each value of x and m
for i in range(200):

    for j in range(3):
        bessel = J(j, xvals[i])
        print("x: {}, m: {}, Val: {}".format(xvals[i], j, bessel))      #Print statement to check the program is functioning correctly before moving on to the next stage
```

Comment: The first argument to `integrate()` should be a function. You're calling the function, not passing a reference to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
return (1 / np.pi) * integrate(func(0, m, x), 0, np.pi, 10000)
```

In your function `J`, you are giving a function call as a parameter, i.e. its return value. Change `func(0, m, x)` to `func` and it should work.

Edit:

The correct answer was to pass a lambda expression: `lambda i: func(i, m, x)`. Credit goes to Barmar.

Comment: Unfortunately that just gives a different error:

"TypeError: func() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'o', 'm', and 'x'"

Comment: That's because in each call to that function in `integrate()`, you are only passing one parameter when three are required - `c = f(a + i*h)` and `Area = h*(0.5*f(a) + 0.5*f(b) + s)`

Comment: Try using `lambda i: func(i, m, x)`

Comment: Is that to replace `def func(o, m, x): ...`?

Comment: No, that is to replace `func(0, m, x)` in your `integrate()` call

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. Out of curiosity, what was the difference does adding `lambda i:` make to how the program runs. I don't fully understand the difference.

Comment: Basically, when you do `func(0, m, x)` you get the return value of `func`. Lambda expressions are [anonymous functions](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) that are quite useful in situations like these, where you need to pass a function object with one or more static valued variables.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!