# Issue with plotting a function defined recursively and involving integrations

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, recursion, scipy

I am coding a blueprint for an algorithm of calculating roots and weights of a polynomial. I used [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-legendre-polynomials-using-recursion-relation/) as a reference guide but wasn't able to pass Rys(X, n, t2) function in matplotlib.plot(). I got:

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (100,) and (1,)
```

I don't understand why it works for one case and doesn't for another. I decided to calculate the Rys function for a set of t2 values, so did a `t2 = np.linspace(0, 1, points)`, tried to use it as an argument for Rys() and started getting nearly all sorts of issues.

First, I could not pass my integrands to scipy.integrate.fixed_quad() and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088264/getting-a-typeerror-numpy-float64-object-is-not-callable-error-in-program) I should've used lambda functions. Not sure if I did it right, either way, the overall result of my efforts currently is:

```
  File "/***/polynomial.py", line 66, in <module>
    Rn = Rys(X, order, 0.56)
  File "/***/polynomial.py", line 50, in Rys
    top_integral_a = scipy.integrate.fixed_quad(lambda t2 : top_integrand_a(t2, X, n), a = 0.0, b = 1.0, n = 10)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_quadrature.py", line 150, in fixed_quad
    return (b-a)/2.0 * np.sum(w*func(y, *args), axis=-1), None
  File "/***/polynomial.py", line 50, in <lambda>
    top_integral_a = scipy.integrate.fixed_quad(lambda t2 : top_integrand_a(t2, X, n), a = 0.0, b = 1.0, n = 10)
  File "/***/polynomial.py", line 24, in top_integrand_a
    return np.exp(-X * t2) * Rys(X, n - 1, t2) * t2 * Rys(X, n - 1, t2)
  File "/***/polynomial.py", line 52, in Rys
    alpha = top_integral_a / bottom_integral_a
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'tuple'
```

Why am I getting this error? In my idea, the function works with individual numbers, not with arrays, not with tuples. It's just called multiple times for different numbers in the input.

The full code:

```
import math
import scipy
from scipy import integrate
from scipy import special
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

pi = np.pi

def top_integrand_a(t2, X, n):
    return np.exp(-X * t2) * Rys(X, n - 1, t2) * t2 * Rys(X, n - 1, t2)

def bottom_integrand_a(t2, X, n):
    return np.exp(-X * t2) * Rys(X, n - 1, t2) * Rys(X, n - 1, t2)

def bottom_integrand_b(t2, X, n):
    np.exp(-X * t2) * Rys(X, n - 2, t2) * Rys(X, n - 2, t2)

def Rys(X, n, t2):

    n = n - 1

    if (n == -1):
        return 0

    elif (n == 0):

        top = (np.sqrt(pi) * special.erf(np.sqrt(X))) / (4 * pow(X, 1.5)) - ((np.exp(-X)) / (2 * X))
        bottom = (np.sqrt(pi) * special.erf(np.sqrt(X))) / (2 * np.sqrt(X))
        alpha = top / bottom
        a.append(alpha)

        return 1

    else:
        
        top_integral_a = scipy.integrate.fixed_quad(lambda t2 : top_integrand_a(t2, X, n), a = 0.0, b = 1.0, n = 10)
        bottom_integral_a = scipy.integrate.fixed_quad(lambda t2 : bottom_integrand_a(t2, X, n), a = 0.0, b = 1.0, n = 10)
        alpha = top_integral_a / bottom_integral_a
        a.append(alpha)

        top_integral_b = bottom_integral_a
        bottom_integral_b = scipy.integrate.fixed_quad(lambda t2 : bottom_integrand_b(t2, X, n), a = 0.0, b = 1.0, n = 10)
        beta = top_integral_b / bottom_integral_b
        b.append(beta)

        return (t2 - alpha) * Rys(X, n - 1) - beta * Rys(X, n - 2)

points = 100
X = 2.0e4
order = 5

Rn = Rys(X, order, 0.56)
print(Rn)
```

Comment: Your "full code" is inconsistent. At the end of `Rys(x, n, t2)` you're calling it with 2 arguments. Your `bottom_integrand_b` doesn't have a `return` statement, so it returns `None`. Finally, if you look at the docs for https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.fixed_quad.html, you'll see it returns a two-tuple and your integral values need to pick the first value from that. This would also be much easier for you to diagnose if you stepped through the code with a debugger.

Comment: Looks like the first error is caused by `plot(x,y)` where `x` has 100 values, and `y` just one.  Have you tried to figure out why `y` is like that?   Did you look at that `y`?  check its `dtype`.

Comment: Indeed, it was inconsistent. I fixed these issues and now have an too long recursion issue. The recursions here cannot be over 1000 calls long.
I guess I'll just write it in C++ instead.